# Service oriented architecture spring-mvc

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc controller that returns a pojo :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody Person addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
  return personService.add(person);
}
```

This controller is located in war file A, on server A.

I have another spring app, war file b, that may go on a different server or the same server.  Whats the best way to access the addPerson method ?  Via an http request or packaging up the class file (and dependicies) as a jar and including in war file b ?  Or am I getting the wrong end of the stick and should do something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "best way", it all depends on the circumstances. Does war A rely on a lot of external dependencies or databases? If so, it may be disadvantageous to including it into war B (in effect duplicating the load on all external dependencies) and a web-service approach might be better. If A is a very simple application, maybe the extra complexity of a web-service integration would be overkill. Maybe they should be merged altogether?

In general though, you should ask yourself (or whoever wrote A and B) why they are split into two different application. There is probably a reason for it, and if it's a compelling one you should probably maintain the separation and go for web-service calls.

Comment: is there an example of calling/consuming a webservice from within a spring-mvc controller ? Say for example my addPerson method had to call "getAddress(id)" or "/Address/13" ?

Comment: There are loads of examples. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82146-Spring-RESTful-Client-Server-tutorial is a REST tutorial (using the RestTemplate from Springs web/client module). It's XML-based but can be modified easily to use JSON (using the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-client-access).